# How do I bind values correctly in a Blazor EditForm (.NET8)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-8.0

I'm trying to bind values  fields in my EditForm in Blazor. I'm using .NET8 and the project itself is a Blazor Web App (so I can utilise both server + client side processing).

For some reason no matter what I've tried I can't get the form to bind to values. I even added an OnInitialized override to initialize my identity class (made up of three strings: username, password, database) to ensure the model is there to write the input to but it just won't work.

Something I have noticed is that when I click Login it seems to reinitialize the page which obviously sets everything in the identity model back to null. Not sure how to fix this - it should be so simple from reading everything on Google.

Here is my code:

```
@page "/logon"
@inject NavigationManager NavManager
@layout BlankLayout

<style>
    .container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        min-height: 100vh;
    }

    .login-box {
        text-align: left;
        font-family: 'Segoe UI';
        background-color: #ffffff;
        padding: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }

    .login-image {
        max-width: 465px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .form-group {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        font-family: 'Segoe UI';
    }

    .form-control {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 8px 12px;
        border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
</style>

<EditForm Model="@identity" OnValidSubmit="@LoginMethod" FormName="loginForm">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <div class="container">
        <div class="login-box">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <label for="username">Username</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <InputText @bind-Value="identity.Username" id="username" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <InputText @bind-Value="identity.Password" type="password" id="password" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <label for="logonTo" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Database</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <InputSelect @bind-Value="identity.Database" id="logonTo" class="form-control">
                        <option value="local">Local</option>
                    </InputSelect>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</EditForm>


@code {
    private Identity identity = new Identity();
    private bool loading;

    public void LoginMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Username: {identity.Username}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Password: {identity.Password}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Database: {identity.Database}");


        switch (identity.Database)
        {
            case "Local":
                // Check if user identity exists


                // If false throw errors
                if (identity.Username == null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("User doesnt exist not logging in");
                }
                else
                {
                    // Redirect to home page if identity found
                    NavManager.NavigateTo("/");
                }


                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

    }


}
```

All the console.writelines are printing out null values - I must be missing something fundamental?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents().AddServerComponents();
```

In your Logon component:

```
@attribute [RenderModeServer]
```

It's ok now:
[image]

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much Ruikai been spent one too many weeks trying to figure this one out

Comment: In my case, I used the [`@rendermode InteractiveServer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-8.0#rendermode) on my page with a `EditForm`.