# How do I implement extended user properties in the Blazor UI for Identity in .NET 8?

Tags: c#, data-binding, blazor, asp.net-core-identity, .net-8.0

I'm having problems saving data to extended user properties in the Blazor UI for Identity .NET 8.

My problem is that in the `OnValidSubmitAsync()` method in `Components/Account/Pages/Manage/Index.razor`, the phone number is being saved, but nothing else.

I have narrowed the problem down to that these lines inside `OnValidSubmitAsync()` aren't able to get the form field data:

```
user.Introduction = Input.Introduction;
user.Website = Input.Website;
user.Instagram = Input.Instagram;
user.TwitterX = Input.TwitterX;
user.Facebook = Input.Facebook;
```

If I try to hard code a value, it is being saved successfully:

```
user.Website = "www.test.com";
```

So I guess it's a data-binding issue.

I have renamed the `ApplicationUser` to `User`, and it is inheriting from `IdentityUser`:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string LastName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public bool HasProfileImage { get; set; }
    public bool HasBackgropImage { get; set; }
    public string Introduction { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string? Website { get; set; }
    public string? Instagram { get; set; }
    public string? TwitterX { get; set; }
    public string? Facebook { get; set; }
    public List<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; } = [];
}
```

My `DataContext` is configured correctly, and all the properties from the model are found as columns in the `AspNetUser` table in the database.

In `Program.cs`:

```
builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<User>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext>()
    .AddSignInManager()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

I have manually entered test data in SQL Server Management Studio, and all the extended fields are being successfully loaded in `OnInitializedAsync()` and displayed correctly in the form fields.

This is my entire `Index.razor`:

```
@page "/Account/Manage"

@inject UserManager<User> UserManager
@inject SignInManager<User> SignInManager
@inject IdentityUserAccessor UserAccessor
@inject IdentityRedirectManager RedirectManager

<PageTitle>Profile</PageTitle>

<h3>Profile</h3>
<StatusMessage />

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <EditForm Model="Input" FormName="profile" OnValidSubmit="OnValidSubmitAsync" method="post">
            <DataAnnotationsValidator />
            <ValidationSummary class="text-danger" role="alert" />
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                <input type="text" value="@username" class="form-control" disabled />
                <label for="username" class="form-label"><i class="bi bi-envelope-at"></i> Brukernavn</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                <InputText @bind-Value="Input.PhoneNumber" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone number" />
                <label for="phone-number" class="form-label"><i class="bi bi-phone"></i> Phone number</label>
                <ValidationMessage For="() => Input.PhoneNumber" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                <InputText @bind-Value="Input.Introduction" class="form-control" placeholder="Introduction" />
                <label for="introduction" class="form-label"><i class="bi bi-blockquote-left"></i> Introduction</label>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex flex-row row row-cols-2">
                <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                    <InputText @bind-Value="Input.Website" class="form-control" placeholder="Website" />
                    <label for="website" class="form-label ms-3"><i class="bi bi-globe"></i> Website</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                    <InputText @bind-Value="Input.Instagram" class="form-control" placeholder="Instagram" />
                    <label for="instagram" class="form-label ms-3"><i class="bi bi-instagram"></i> Instagram</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                    <InputText @bind-Value="Input.TwitterX" class="form-control" placeholder="Twitter/X" />
                    <label for="twitterX" class="form-label ms-3"><i class="bi bi-twitter-x"></i> Twitter/X</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                    <InputText @bind-Value="Input.Facebook" class="form-control" placeholder="Facebook" />
                    <label for="facebook" class="form-label ms-3"><i class="bi bi-facebook"></i> Facebook</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-success">
                <i class="bi bi-save"></i>
                Save
            </button>
        </EditForm>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    private User user = default!;
    private string? username;
    private string? phoneNumber;

    [CascadingParameter]
    private HttpContext HttpContext { get; set; } = default!;

    [SupplyParameterFromForm(FormName = "profile")]
    private InputModel Input { get; set; } = new();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        user = await UserAccessor.GetRequiredUserAsync(HttpContext);
        username = await UserManager.GetUserNameAsync(user);
        phoneNumber = await UserManager.GetPhoneNumberAsync(user);

        // These are all working. All the data is loaded from DB:
        Input.PhoneNumber ??= phoneNumber;
        Input.Introduction = user.Introduction;
        Input.Website = user.Website;
        Input.Instagram = user.Instagram;
        Input.TwitterX = user.TwitterX;
        Input.Facebook = user.Facebook;
    }

    private async Task OnValidSubmitAsync()
    {
        if (Input.PhoneNumber != phoneNumber)
        {
            var setPhoneResult = await UserManager.SetPhoneNumberAsync(user, Input.PhoneNumber);
            if (!setPhoneResult.Succeeded)
            {
                RedirectManager.RedirectToCurrentPageWithStatus("Error: Could not set phone number.", HttpContext);
            }
        }

        // The form field data is not being copied to the user-object here:
        user.Introduction = Input.Introduction;
        user.Website = Input.Website;
        user.Instagram = Input.Instagram;
        user.TwitterX = Input.TwitterX;
        user.Facebook = Input.Facebook;

        // Hard coded values are successfully saved:
        user.Website = "www.test.com";

        await UserManager.UpdateAsync(user); // This line is working

        await SignInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(user);
        RedirectManager.RedirectToCurrentPageWithStatus($"Your profile was updated.", HttpContext);
    }

    private sealed class InputModel
    {
        [Phone]
        [Display(Name = "Phone number")]
        public string? PhoneNumber { get; set; }

        // Exxtended fields
        public string? Introduction { get; set; }
        public string? Website { get; set; }
        public string? Instagram { get; set; }
        public string? TwitterX { get; set; }
        public string? Facebook { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**update #1**

If I comment out these lines in `OnInitializedAsync()`:

```
//Input.Introduction = user.Introduction;
//Input.Website = user.Website;
//Input.Instagram = user.Instagram;
//Input.TwitterX = user.TwitterX;
//Input.Facebook = user.Facebook;
```

... I am then able to save the values. But now they are not displayed in the form fields.

**/end of update #1**

Comment: does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77109458/how-do-i-bind-values-correctly-in-a-blazor-editform-net8

Comment: @jeb No, I already have `builder.Services.AddRazorComponents().AddInteractiveServerComponents();` in my Program.cs. `AddServerComponents()` doesn't seem to exist. It gives an error message.

Comment: Did you migrate the DB after the model changes?

Comment: @Grizzlly Yes, as I said in the question, the database table has all the properties as columns.

Comment: when you WriteLine the ` Input.Facebook;` (in `OnValidSubmit`) does it output the correct value? If yes, does the value flow through the request (in F12)?

Comment: @Alamakanambra I'm not able to CW it, but I can see the SQL query in the output window. The parameter value for the Facebook-field, and all the rest of the extended fields, are always NULL.

Comment: I have a lot of guesses and things to try, which I don't want to pollute the comments with. It will be something "stupid"
Would be possible for you to share the code in runnable project?

Comment: @Alamakanambra I'm sorry, I don't know how I would do that. The project is on GitHub, if you want to check that: https://github.com/stiandroid/MenuPlanner

Answer (score 0):

You are rewriting the `Input` in `OnInitializedAsync` before it goes through the `OnValidSubmitAsync`.

Apparently when using SSR with form binding (`[SupplyParameterFromForm]`) it goes through the `OnInitializedAsync` when you submit the form (before jumping to `OnValidSubmitAsync` ). And inside there you are rewriting the `Input` by user values.

Solution:

```
 [SupplyParameterFromForm]
    private InputModel? Input { get; set; } //no new here

  protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        user = await UserAccessor.GetRequiredUserAsync(HttpContext);
        username = await UserManager.GetUserNameAsync(user);
        phoneNumber = await UserManager.GetPhoneNumberAsync(user);

        if (Input == null) //it is not null when when SuppliedFromForm
        {
            Input = new();
            Input.PhoneNumber ??= phoneNumber;
            Input.Introduction = user.Introduction;
            Input.Website = user.Website;
            Input.Instagram = user.Instagram;
            Input.TwitterX = user.TwitterX;
            Input.Facebook = user.Facebook;
        }
    }
```

Comment: No, that did not have any effect. Note that the default field for phone number is working without the @: `@bind-Value="Input.PhoneNumber"`

Comment: I added an update to my question. Could you see if you can make any sense of it?

Comment: I get "InvalidOperationException: EditForm requires either a Model parameter, or an EditContext parameter, please provide one of these.". It seems the `InputModel` can't be nullable.

Comment: @Stian You have to specify the Model or EditContext, that doesn't mean it cannot be null prior to ` OnInitializedAsync` . Check official docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms/binding?view=aspnetcore-8.0 . In your original code, you have `<EditForm Model="Input"`, you sure it's still there? With the proposed changes, the code works.

Comment: Yes, I still have `Model="Input"` on the form. With your proposed null-check and subsequently setting `Input = new();`, I get the exception "InvalidOperationException: EditForm requires either a Model parameter, or an EditContext parameter".